# Join 2 tables with row number in query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to connect 2 tables which is complex. The Contract tab is the link between the two tables. The large table is queried with Row Number and the small table may only be connected with WHERE type 'AI' because the info tab contains the data that I need.

Here is the large table

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        z.plan_auftrag, 
        b.aunr as contract,
        b.user_n_07,
        b.user_c_47,
        b.user_n_08,
        b.erranf_dat,
        b.erranf_zeit,
        s.a_status,
        b.user_f_25,
        b.user_f_26,
        b.user_c_56,
        b.soll_menge_pri,
        b.user_c_49, 
        b.kunden_bez, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.aunr ORDER BY b.erranf_zeit) AS [row_number]
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
        ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] s
        ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m
        ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr
        AND s.masch_nr = 'FIMI3'
        AND s.a_status IN ('V','L','U')
        AND m.kennz = 'M'
        AND s.eingeplant = ('M')
        AND b.a_typ IN ('AU','AG')
) AS x
WHERE x.row_number = 1
ORDER BY x.a_status ASC
    , x.erranf_dat ASC
    , x.erranf_zeit ASC;
```

Here the small table

```
SELECT info1, left([key],9) as contract
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_hyinfo]
WHERE typ = 'AI'
```

Result large Table

[image]

Result small table

[image]

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with emphasis on *minimal* we don't need your production query, just the simplest query which illustrates the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join the small table to the large table before selecting it.

```
SELECT x.*,
info.info1
FROM
(SELECT 
    z.plan_auftrag, 
    b.aunr as contract,
    b.user_n_07,
    b.user_c_47,
    b.user_n_08,
    b.erranf_dat,
    b.erranf_zeit,
    s.a_status,
    b.user_f_25,
    b.user_f_26,
    b.user_c_56,
    b.soll_menge_pri,
    b.user_c_49, 
    b.kunden_bez
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.aunr ORDER BY b.erranf_zeit) AS [row_number]
    FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrags_zusatz] z
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[auftrags_bestand] b
    ON z.auftrag_nr = b.aunr
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_auftrag_status] s
    ON b.auftrag_nr = s.auftrag_nr
    JOIN [hydra1].[hydadm].[mlst_hy] m
    ON s.auftrag_nr = m.auftrag_nr
    AND s.masch_nr = 'FIMI3'
    AND s.a_status IN ('V','L','U')
    AND m.kennz = 'M'
    AND s.eingeplant = ('M')
    AND b.a_typ IN ('AU','AG')
) AS x
JOIN
(SELECT info1, left([key],9) as contract
FROM [hydra1].[hydadm].[v_hyinfo]
WHERE typ = 'AI'
) info ON x.contract = info.contract
WHERE    x.row_number = 1
ORDER BY x.a_status ASC
, x.erranf_dat ASC
, x.erranf_zeit ASC;
```